# Using value outside galois field and do calculations inside

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cryptography

currently, I'm working Shamir Secret Sharing algorithm and for not so big numbers (long passwords more than 7 chars) my calculations are broken because of overflows.

The case is this:
I have a big number: suppose 49584309583 and if I use it in calculations eventually be lost of precision so I've heard that calculations can be done in Galois Field (GF) for example in $\operatorname{GF}(251)$

So the question is: can I get my number to be converted back from $\operatorname{GF}$ to outside $\operatorname{GF}$?

Comment: There is no overflow in Finite Fields. Just choose a field size that covers your secret size.

Comment: Hmm, I've got password that I want to convert to number. Depending on lenth of password will be shorter or longer and eventually it will overflow my finite field space. So how should I encode password to fit in my field ?

Comment: [Polynomial bases](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70235/18298) where each coefficient can represent some part depending on the choice of $(\operatorname{GF}{p^m})$

Comment: can u explain more on this ?

Comment: Consider this you use $GF(p^m)$ than in the polynomial basis each coefficient is an element of $GF(p)$ and can store up to $m$ slots. If the bit size of $p \approx k$ then you can embed $km$ bits into polynomial as an element of the field $GF(p^m)$. Remember $GF(p^m)$ has $p^m$ elements...